# Obtaining a Remote User's guid in ASP.NET with C#

Tags: asp.net, guid

I am attempting to build a simple web application in ASP.NET with C#. The purpose of this application is to obtain a guid for the user’s Windows account login.

The intended effect is that a user, on his or her own windows machine, attempts to login to this site. The server looks at the user’s credentials, and pulls the guid for his or her windows login on their own network. The guid is then checked against a database, and if it matches one that we have stored previously, we authenticate them and redirect.
The issue I am having is that any credentials I try to obtain, if I can even get any, are always those of the server, not of the remote user.

In the `web.config`, I have tried setting `authentication mode = "windows"`, denying anonymous users, and setting `identity impersonate="true"` . I have also tried many permutations of these.

Neither `HTTPContext` nor  `User.Identity` returned anything. `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` and anything through `System.Security.Principal` returned the server’s credentials.

This did, however, work on my `localhost`. It failed whenever I published it to an external IIS server.

All I want to do is obtain a guid for theremote user’s windows login. Is it even possible to do so? If so, any help pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The way that I've seen this work on banking websites is that the user is somehow two-factor authenticated (my bank calls me at the number I have on file with them and gives me a temporary six digit access code that I type into their registration page), and then you store a GUID of your own choosing or some other authentication token in a cookie on their browser.  If they clear cookies, they have to two-factor authenticate again.

Answer (score 0):

The following is quoted from [msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/43e05117-d25f-4489-af19-41d2dad33b33/). I don't know if this would help you or not.

> In .Net 3.5 the UserPrinciple class was introduced under the
> System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespace. It has a
> property for both getting the current UserPrinciple and the Guid from
> it.
>
> Example:

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
Guid currentGuid = UserPrincipal.Current.Guid;
```

Comment: You may also want to look at this. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163295.aspx

Comment: Yeah, but this has nothing to do with the user's machine.